# Restrict S3 object access using CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I need to restrict access to S3 objects using cloudfront. Hence the users will be hitting the cloudfront url instead of S3.

How do I specify which users can access the cloudfront URL.

I am aware of OAI and related bucket access but that does not allow me to restrict the user group.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Signed URLs for this purpose. You can generate the URL for your specific user, share it with them, and limit access to that URL with the constraints available.

In one case I generated a very short-lived Signed URL and redirected the user to that URL, so it essentially only worked for the user who made the request. Limiting the lifetime to a few seconds and access to the client's IP address was sufficient for my case.

AWS docs here on Private Content: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html